# trying to send emails in java using javamail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, send

I am trying to send emails to an email account (gmail) I have set up made for dynamic reminders for when I am not home using javamail, but all sample code I have used compiles correctly, but gives me an error when I try to run the code (javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException).Here I have supplied a section of code that I am currently using.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String username = "username@gmail.com";
    final String password = "password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Sample Subject");
        message.setText("Sample body");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have 2-step verification settings for your account at GMail? Try to disable it. You can do it [here](https://myaccount.google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens when Gmail has disabled access by "insecure apps".

Can you try this: loggin into gmail web app and open this [url](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and select the “Activate” option.

In [my post](http://www.jasnat.com/tutorials/java-ee/how-to-send-mail-with-java/) you can see the detail